# Sending a Multipart email with (HTML, Plain Text and Attachment) in PHP

Tags: php, html, email

I am sending a multi-part email with php with html formatting and an attachment...
All is working fine but when the user receiving that email from our website it is showing the boundary as well in last of the HTML part.
But when i remove the boundary line the email showing file contents as base64 (no attachment).

```
 if ( isset($_POST['submit']) )
 {
 $to = 'admin@abc.com';
 $FromSubmitting = $_POST['submitting'];
$FromTitle = $_POST['title'];
$FromName = $_POST['name'];
$FromDesignation = $_POST['designation'];
$FromQualification = $_POST['qualification'];
$FromInstitute = $_POST['institute_address'];
$FromHomeAddress = $_POST['home_address'];
$FromEmail = $_POST['email'];
$FromWorkPhone = $_POST['work_phone_number'];
$FromHomePhone = $_POST['home_phone_number'];
$FromMobilePhone = $_POST['mobile_phone_number'];
$FromPresentingAuthor = $_POST['presenting_author'];
$FromConferenceTheme = $_POST['conference_theme'];
$FromTypeOfSubmission = $_POST['type_of_submission'];

$subject = "New ".$FromSubmitting." Submitted From: ".$FromName;


/* GET File Variables */
$tmpName = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'];
$fileName = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
/* Start of headers */
$headers = "From: $FromEmail";

if (file($tmpName)) {  
/* Reading file ('rb' = read binary)  */
$file = fopen($tmpName,'rb'); 
$data = fread($file,filesize($tmpName));
fclose($file);   /* a boundary string */  
$randomVal = md5(time());  
$mimeBoundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$randomVal}x";   

/* Header for File Attachment */  
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n";  
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" ;  
$headers .= " boundary=\"{$mimeBoundary}\"";   

/* Multipart Boundary above message */  

 $message .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n"
. "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n"
. "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n"  
. "<table>
<tr><td>Submission Type:</td><td>$FromSubmitting</td></tr>
<tr><td>Name:</td><td>$FromTitle $FromName</td></tr>
<tr><td>Designation:</td><td>$FromDesignation</td></tr>
<tr><td>Qualification:</td><td>$FromQualification</td></tr>
<tr><td>Institute:</td><td>$FromInstitute</td></tr>
<tr><td>Home Address:</td><td>$FromHomeAddress</td></tr>
<tr><td>Work Phone:</td><td>$FromWorkPhone</td>
<td>Home Phone:</td>
<td>$FromHomePhone</td><td>Mobile Phone:</td>
<td>$FromMobilePhone</td></tr>
<tr><td>Presenting Author:</td><td>$FromPresentingAuthor</td></tr>
<tr><td>Conference Theme:</td><td>$FromConferenceTheme</td></tr>
<tr><td>Type of Submission:</td><td>$FromTypeOfSubmission</td></tr>
</table>"
.  "--{$mimeBoundary}\n"; // when removing this line it shows Image-2


/* Encoding file data */  
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));   

/* Adding attchment-file to message*/  
$message .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" 
.  "Content-Type: {$fileType};\n" 
.  " name=\"{$fileName}\"\n" 
.  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" 
.  $data . "\n\n" 
.  "--{$mimeBoundary}--\n";
}

$flgchk = mail ("$to", "$subject", "$message", "$headers"); 

}
```

Email Screen Shot **Image-1** :
[image]

Email Screen Shot **Image-2** :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try this.

/* Adding attchment-file to message*/

```
$message .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n"
."Content-Type: application/octet-stream;\n" 
.  " name=\"{$fileName}\"\n" 
.  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" 
.  $data . "\n\n" 
.  "--{$mimeBoundary}--\n";
```